# Display progress bar in a gulp stream

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

Is there a method to display the progress bar in gulp when copying certain files?

```
gulp.task('release:step-2', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.copy_src, { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.dest.app));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) with Gulp.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var progress = require('progress-stream');

var filePath = config.copy_src;
var fileSize = fs.statSync(filePath).size;

var progressStream = progress({
  length: fileSize,
  time: 100,
  objectMode: true
});

progressStream.on('progress', function (stats) {
  console.log(Math.round(stats.percentage) + '%');
});

gulp.task('release:step-2', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.copy_surc, { dot: true })
    .pipe(progressStream)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.dest.app));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but it`s give an error on finding fileSize. Anyway, this will print an progress for each file not for grouped object.